# sql date range in column and count by group

Tags: sql, date, pivot, range

I am trying to get a report where you can select a date range and get some counts.
My table is something like this

```
--------------------------------------
RecID|AgentID|date
--------------------------------------
1    |00123  | 05/09/2012 16:28:49
2    |00123  | 05/09/2012 17:28:49
3    |00124  | 05/09/2012 18:28:49
4    |00124  | 06/09/2012 19:28:49
5    |00125  | 06/09/2012 20:28:49
```

I want something like

```
--------------------------------------
AgentID|05/09/2012|06/09/2012
--------------------------------------
00123  | 2        | 0
00124  | 1        | 1
00125  | 0        | 1
```

The code I have is

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @INIDate as date,
    @ENDDate as date,
    @INIDateVAR nvarchar(50),
    @ENDDateVAR nvarchar(50)

Set @INIDate = '10-01-2014'
Set @ENDDate = '10-10-2014'


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT agentID';

;WITH dr AS
(

  SELECT MinDate = @INIDate,
         MaxDate = @ENDDate
),
n AS
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MinDate FROM dr), (SELECT MaxDate FROM dr)) + 1)
   d = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1, 
     (SELECT MinDate FROM dr))
 FROM sys.all_objects
)
SELECT @sql += ',
  (Select Count(*) From AllRecordsView) as ' + QUOTENAME(d) 
   FROM n;

SELECT @sql += ' FROM dbo.AllRecordsView Group by AgentID;'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
GO
```

But this gets very slow when I select a big date range and the results I get are of course the count of the complete table.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing is using Reporting Services. That way I can assign all the values from a column as a columns, one per each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the day() function (depends on the database) to extract the day from the date field and use it in the GROUP BY. 
For the range use SQL BETWEEN.

If you still have performance issues, you should create an index on the AgentID and the date column.

`SELECT dateColumn, AgentID, count(AgentID) AS agentCount 

FROM YourTable

WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN '2012-09-05' AND '2012-09-09'

GROUP BY day(dateColumn), AgentID

ORDER BY dateColumn;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. 
Yes this will give me the count grouped by date and agent but not in the format I expect.
I want to have the dates as columns. So a select between dates and every date in the range as a column.