# How to "transpose" date data into columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, pivot, presto

I have a table with `(id, name, creation_timestamp)`

I want to write a query that gives:

```
name, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-16, ... , 2019-10-15
```

Columns date are for the last 30 days.

In each column there will be the count of records per name that matches the date.

I know how to create this as rows

```
select  name
        ,cast ( creation_timestamp as DATE)
        ,count(1)
from my_bale 
group by name, cast ( creation_timestamp as DATE)
```

But this gives me 3 columns and the dates are listed in the 2nd columns.
How can I convert this to the required output?

Lets say that my table has

```
id, name , creation_timestamp
1    A     2019-10-10 21:52:22.904  
2   A     2019-10-10 22:52:22.904   
3   B    2019-10-10 21:52:22.904    
3    C  2019-10-11 21:52:22.904
```

Output should be:

```
name, 2019-09-15, 2019-09-16, ... , 2019-10-10, 2019-10-11, ..., 2019-10-15
 A     0             0                 2           0                0
 B     0             0                 1           0                0
 C     0             0                 0           1                0
```

Similar to the question [sql date range in column and count by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430190/sql-date-range-in-column-and-count-by-group) but it didn't get any answer

I'm using Presto but a native SQL solution is great

Comment: i put your title into google, and, unsurprisingly, there are lots of articles on the subject. to start, check out: https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

Comment: @Jeremy There are not in presto and not with date column. All examples are for static columns.

Comment: @Jeremy Note in your link that the DATE is only 1 column. and the other dimensions are hard coded. Your example is the easy case of what I'm asking. You can't use it to get what i'm after.. you'll need a whole diffrent approach. hence the question to stack overflow. There is only 1 similar solution in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884765/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-with-datetime  but this is very specific to MS SQL. There is no equivalent for presto or standard SQL